# How can I report on the number of people in more than one category?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table in Power BI which contains information on people who are supported by our organisation.  We offer a number of different services and user could access one or more of these services in a given time period.

My table looks like this:

[image: Table]

From here we can see that the user with serial number 102617 accessed two services in January 2020 (Community Services and Publication).

I need to report on how many people have been supported by multiple services.  The output should look something like this:

[image: Output]

I am fairly new to DAX and I know that I need a measure because it needs to calculate within the current filter context (filtered by date range).

I have tried the following code and it gets me part of the way there.

```
Total = 
   SUMX(
      VALUES(Supported[SERIALNUMBER]), 
      CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Supported[Service Type]))
   )
```

If I chart this measure against SERIALNUMBER I get this output:

[image: chart]

This makes me think I'm on the right track because it shows that 6 people are being supported by 3 services - as the sample output above confirms.  But I want that number 6 to be my measure.

All the rest of my report works but I cannot figure out how to do this last part.  Many thanks for any advice offered.

Comment: The easiest way to achieve the result if you add a calculated column. Then calculate for each id/serialNumber or what ever with  a `Distinctcount([Service Type])` or `CountRows(Values([Service Type]))`. It can look like `CALCULATE(Distinctcount([Service Type] ;ALLEXCEPT[Serial Number])` CALCULATE will add the row Values as filters to the calculating table, so you remove all filters except [Serial Number]. If you want to get the measure then give more info about your model e.g. table name for [Serial Number] where values are keys, names of involved  tables and columns.

Comment: `DISTINCTCOUNT(Supported[Service Type])` most probably is enough - you are filtering the table by Serial Number in the chart. I mean Ox axis is a filter.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create a dimension table for the Number of Services.

You can do this using Power Query:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromList({1..List.Count(List.Distinct(Supported[Service Type]))},Splitter.SplitByNothing(),{"Number of Services"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Number of Services", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Or using DAX:

```
Services = GENERATESERIES ( 1, DISTINCTCOUNT ( Supported[Service Type] ) )
```

then rename column as required.

Now you can create a couple of measures:

Number of Services Used:

```
Number of Services Used = DISTINCTCOUNT ( Supported[Service Type] )
```

People:

```
People = 
    COUNTROWS ( 
        FILTER ( 
            SUMMARIZE ( 
                Supported,
                Supported[SERIALNUMBER],
                "NumServices", [Number of Services Used]
            ),
            [NumServices] >= MIN ( Services[Number of Services] ) && 
            [NumServices] <= MAX ( Services[Number of Services] )
        )
    )
```

People (Cumulative):

```
People (Cumulative) = 
    COUNTROWS ( 
        FILTER ( 
            SUMMARIZE ( 
                Supported,
                Supported[SERIALNUMBER],
                "NumServices", [Number of Services Used]
            ),
            [NumServices] >= MIN ( Services[Number of Services] )
        )
    )
```

This gives the following, for your (tiny) data sample:

[image]